# Tabulator - Filtering based on another Tabulator

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, tabulator

I have a Tabulator that contains search results. Here is the code:

```
var table = new Tabulator("#json-table", {
    layout:"fitDataFill",
    //initialFilter:[{field:"title", type:"!=", value:"ignoreList.title"}],
    ajaxURL:tabUrl,
    ajaxResponse:function(url, params, response){
        return Object.values(response);
    },
    columns:
        [{title:"Title", field:"title", align:"center"},
        {title:"Price", field:"price", align:"center"},
        {title:"Shipping Cost", field:"shippingCost.shippingServiceCost.value", align:"center"},
        {title:"Watch List", align:"center", cellClick:function(e, cell){
            var data = cell.getData();
            watchListArray.push(data);
            localStorage.setItem("watchList", JSON.stringify(watchListArray));
    },},
        {title:"Ignore List", align:"center", cellClick:function(e, cell){
            var data = cell.getData();
            ignoreListArray.push(data);
            localStorage.setItem("ignoreList", JSON.stringify(ignoreListArray));
    },
        },
        {title:"Image", align:"center"},
    ],
});
```

I also have another tabulator that contains an Ignore List. Here is the code:

```
ignoreListArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("ignoreList"));

var ignoreList = new Tabulator("#json-table", {
    data:ignoreListArray,
    layout:"fitDataFill",
    columns:
        [{title:"Title", field:"title", align:"center"},
        {title:"Price", field:"price", align:"center"},
        {title:"Shipping Cost", field:"shippingCost.shippingServiceCost.value", align:"center"},
        {title:"Watch List", align:"center"},
        {title:"Ignore List", align:"center"},
        {title:"Image", align:"center"},
        ],
    });
```

I am using `localStorage` to store rows from the search results in the Ignore List Tabulator if the user clicks the Ignore List cell for the row they want to ignore. If a row is put in the Ignore List, I want to make it so this row never shows up in future search results until it is removed from the Ignore List.

Is there built-in filtering that will help me to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

You would need to use a custom filter to achieve this.

In order to filter out the rows you would need a way to compare the rows in the ignore list with those in the table. usually you would assign each row an ***id*** field and then check to see if the id of the row was in the ignore list. I will use this approach in the example, but you could easily adapt it to look for matching values for any property in the row object.

inside our custom filter we will the use the ***filter*** function built into a JavaScript array to find any matches on the array;

```
function customFilter(data, filterParams){
    //data - the data for the row being filtered
    //filterParams - params object passed to the filter

    //check for matches
    var matches = ignoreListArray.filter(function(element){
        return element.id == data.id
    });

    return !matches.length; //allow row if it does not match any row in the ignore list
}

//set filter on table
table.setFilter(customFilter);
```

Full details on using custom filters can be found in the [Filter Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.1/filter)